# How can I authorize an app to publish to a URL's object page news feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, object, authorization, publish

I'm trying to provide a way for a brand page to message particular fans (instead of all fans) by allowing people to like a URL to show their affinity and then publish to the URL's feed so that it gets messaged out to the fan.

Imagine a brand "Foo" with products A, B and C. It may be beneficial to tell people to like Foo on Facebook, but those who want information about products B or C may feel like they're being overwhelmed with information on product A. At the same time, all fans may want general information about the brand. At the same time, the brand may not want the overhead of managing multiple Facebook timelines (see Nike's collection of pages for every possible product/sport). Shell is currently doing this with their [On The Road](http://www.facebook.com/Shell?v=app_369684813048582) page.

In order to do this, I first created an app to publish with and retrieved an app access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID_HERE&client_secret=APP_SECRET_HERE&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Next, I made a page with the Open Graph metadata needed to represent an affinity:

```
<html lang="en">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="APP ID GOES HERE" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"        content="product" /> 
  <meta property="og:site_name"    content="FB Test!" />
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http:///url.to/object.html" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Publishing Test Source" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="Get more info by liking this page!" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"       content="http://url.to/image.jpg" /> 
</head>
<body>
<p>Please wait... - Meta Refresh or Javascript redirect here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Placing a like button for this URL on a page and then liking it, let's me retrieve information by looking it up with either a Graph search:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?http://url.to/object.html
```

...or FQL (which seems to work more reliably):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20id%20from%20object_url%20where%20url%20in%20('http://url.to/object.html')
```

Either will give me an ID for the object like:

```
{
   "http://url.to/object.html": {
      "id": "BIG_OBJECT_ID"
   }
}
```

From what I can tell, I should be able to publish to the news feed of that object like so:

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESSTOKEN|LONGSTRING' -F 'message=Hello World.' https://graph.facebook.com/BIG_OBJECT_ID/feed
```

...but all I get is an authorization error. There's some step in the middle that I'm missing. I assumed that by tying the object to an app_ID, one would be allowed to publish to the other. I think what I'm missing is a process where I authorize the app to manage the page? Do I need an admin_ID to act as an intermediary?